# Cygwin header file location

Tags: linux, cygwin

My OS is `Windows 8`, I'm using `cygwin 1.7.34(0.285/5/3)`.
Where are the header files located in cygwin? For instance, I need to add an additional header file, say `transport.h` to already existing in order to use it as `#include <transport.h>`. What should I put it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents is that you shouldn't put the file in one of the default system header paths - you should put it into whatever directory you want (`/usr/local/libfoo_v1.0/include` being a pretty common convention, with the library itself installed into `/usr/local/libfoo_v1.0/lib`) and then point the compiler to that directory with `-I/usr/local/libfoo_v1.0/include` on the compiler command line.